# Navicat Monitor Uninstall from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, uninstall

Whenever I access `localhost:3000`
there Navicat is always there.
Anyone please help me to get rid of it.
TIA

[image: localhost:3000 alswats showing this]

Comment: I have some other apps that use port 3000 by default, that's why its causing too much troubles.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I ran `sudo apt-get remove navicatmonitor` to solve the problem.

Comment: worked for me thanks.
but how to resolve this : `userdel: user navicatmonitor is currently used by process 2171` ?